# How to dynamically find and invoke Swift functions based on names?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a calculator app in SwiftUI as part of an iOS development course. I've created a class hierarchy for buttons. The idea is that each button has a label (`1`, `2`, `+`, `-` etc), and a type; the type determines what action is taken when the button is pressed. For number buttons, pressing them appends the label to the already accumulated text; for binary operators like `+`, pressing them takes the two numbers accumulated so far and performs an addition.

```
class BinaryOperatorButton: CalculatorButton {
    convenience init(_ label: String) {
        self.init(label, type: .binaryOp)
    }
    override func action(n1: String, n2: String?) -> String {
        guard let x = Float(n1) else {
            fatalError("\(n1) is not a number")
        }
        guard let n = n2, let y = Float(n) else {
            fatalError("\(String(describing: n2)) is not a number")
        }
        
        switch label {
        case K.Operator.Plus.label:
            return format(x + y)
        case K.Operator.Minus.label:
            return format(x - y)
        case K.Operator.Times.label:
            return format(x * y)
        default:
            return format(x / y)
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but for even cleaner code, I'd like to use the label, `+` for example, to find the corresponding Swift function dynamically, and get rid of the switch block completely. It seems like this is possible using selectors, but could not find any examples showing exactly what I'm looking for. I'm using Xcode 11.5, with Swift 5.